# Video capturing crashing on S5

Tags: android, camera, titanium, appcelerator

I have created one Android module to invoke camera and restrict the size of video to 15MB. It works on all devices. But on s5 it is crashed before reaching the onResult callback.Logcat errors and code is attached below.

**Code**

```
/**


* This file was auto-generated by the Titanium Module SDK helper for Android
 * Appcelerator Titanium Mobile
 * Copyright (c) 2009-2010 by Appcelerator, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 * Licensed under the terms of the Apache Public License
 * Please see the LICENSE included with this distribution for details.
 *
 */
package com.ex.videomodule;

import org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollDict;
import org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy;
import org.appcelerator.kroll.annotations.Kroll;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.TiC;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.util.Log;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConfig;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConvert;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.LayoutArrangement;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIView;

import org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication;




import org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiActivityResultHandler;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiActivitySupport;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.File;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollFunction;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


// This proxy can be created by calling VideoModule.createExample({message: "hello world"})
@Kroll.proxy(creatableInModule=VideoModuleModule.class)
public class ExampleProxy extends TiViewProxy implements TiActivityResultHandler
{
    // Standard Debugging variables
    private static final String LCAT = "ExampleProxy";
    private static final boolean DBG = TiConfig.LOGD;

    private int REQ_CODE_CAPTURE_VIDEO = 1;

    Uri mVideoUri;
    String mVideoPath;

    protected KrollFunction successCallback;
    protected KrollFunction errorCallback;

    private class ExampleView extends TiUIView 
    {
        public ExampleView(TiViewProxy proxy) {
            super(proxy);
            LayoutArrangement arrangement = LayoutArrangement.DEFAULT;

            if (proxy.hasProperty(TiC.PROPERTY_LAYOUT)) {
                String layoutProperty = TiConvert.toString(proxy.getProperty(TiC.PROPERTY_LAYOUT));
                if (layoutProperty.equals(TiC.LAYOUT_HORIZONTAL)) {
                    arrangement = LayoutArrangement.HORIZONTAL;
                } else if (layoutProperty.equals(TiC.LAYOUT_VERTICAL)) {
                    arrangement = LayoutArrangement.VERTICAL;
                }
            }
            setNativeView(new TiCompositeLayout(proxy.getActivity(), arrangement));
        }

        @Override
        public void processProperties(KrollDict d)
        {
            super.processProperties(d);
        }
    }


    // Constructor
    public ExampleProxy()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public TiUIView createView(Activity activity)
    {
        TiUIView view = new ExampleView(this);
        view.getLayoutParams().autoFillsHeight = true;
        view.getLayoutParams().autoFillsWidth = true;
        return view;
    }

    // Handle creation options
    @Override
    public void handleCreationDict(KrollDict options)
    {
        super.handleCreationDict(options);

        if (options.containsKey("message")) {
            Log.d(LCAT, "example created with message: " + options.get("message"));
        }
    }

    // Methods
    @Kroll.method
    public void printMessage(String message)
    {
        Log.d(LCAT, "printing message: " + message);
    }


    @Kroll.getProperty @Kroll.method
    public String getMessage()
    {
        return "Hello World from my module";
    }

    @Kroll.setProperty @Kroll.method
    public void setMessage(String message)
    {
        Log.d(LCAT, "Tried setting module message to: " + message);
    }


    @Kroll.method
    public void registerCallback(HashMap options){
    Log.d(LCAT, "inside onAppCreate");


        successCallback = (KrollFunction) options.get("callback"); 
        errorCallback = (KrollFunction) options.get("errorCallback"); 
    }
    @Kroll.method
    private void captureVideo(String path){

        mVideoPath = path;
        File mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
                       +mVideoPath);
         Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
         mVideoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);

         intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mVideoUri);
         intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.videoQuality", 0);

         intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.sizeLimit",15728640L); 
         Activity activity = TiApplication.getInstance().getCurrentActivity();
        TiActivitySupport support = (TiActivitySupport) activity;
        support.launchActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_CAPTURE_VIDEO, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(Activity activity, int thisRequestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.d(LCAT, "onResult "+resultCode);

         if (resultCode == 0) {

            HashMap map = new HashMap();
            map.put("message", "Cancelled");
            errorCallback.call(getKrollObject(), map);
        } else {
            if (mVideoUri != null) {

                Log.d(LCAT, "onResult videro captured " + mVideoUri.getPath());
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+mVideoPath);

                if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {

                    Log.d(LCAT, "onResult File exists " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+mVideoPath);

                    HashMap data1 = new HashMap();
                    data1.put("video",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ mVideoPath);
                    successCallback.call(getKrollObject(), data1);

                } else {

                    mVideoUri = null;
                    mVideoPath = null;
                    HashMap map = new HashMap();

                    map.put("message", "Failed To load Image 1");
                    errorCallback.call(getKrollObject(), map);


                }
            } else {

                mVideoUri = null;
                mVideoPath = null;
                HashMap map = new HashMap();
                map.put("message", "Failed To load Image 2");
                errorCallback.call(getKrollObject(), map);
            }
        }

            Log.d(LCAT, "onResult videro captured"+resultCode);


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Activity activity, int requestCode, Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(LCAT, "onError "+ e.getMessage());
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
            map.put("message", "Cancelled");
            errorCallback.call(getKrollObject(), map);
    }

}
```

**LOG**

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity
> {com.ex.sample/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.view.OrientationEventListener.disable()' on a null object
> reference     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4893)
>   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4911)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:210)
>   at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1758)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void android.view.OrientationEventListener.disable()' on a
> null object reference     at
> org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onDestroy(TiBaseActivity.java:1373)
>   at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity.onDestroy(TiActivity.java:29)
>   at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6809)  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1169)
>   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4871)
>   ... 10 more
```

**Sometimes getting below crash**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.removeAllViews()' on a null object
>   reference     at
>   ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIActivityIndicator.setStyle(TiUIActivityIndicator.java:164)
>     at
>   ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIActivityIndicator.processProperties(TiUIActivityIndicator.java:86)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.setModelListener(KrollProxy.java:1209)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:502)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:493)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:471)
>     at
>   ti.modules.titanium.ui.ActivityIndicatorProxy.handleHide(ActivityIndicatorProxy.java:94)
>     at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:259)
>     at
>   ti.modules.titanium.ui.ActivityIndicatorProxy.handleMessage(ActivityIndicatorProxy.java:67)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Comment: override onDestroy method and finish all the activities inside the method

Comment: Were to implement onDestroy Method? in module ?

Comment: Inside your Activity

Comment: ok.can you check new log

Comment: try like this inside onDestroy method call removeAllViews method

Comment: How to add onDestroy method in titanium

Comment: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Activity          refer this one